# Why is my function get_data() not called?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am writing a Python script that uses multiprocessing to manage some data variables.
Why does the function `get_data()` never get called in this python code?

The output from the code is:

```
Start it

Data is [('A', 5), ('B', 3), ('C', 3), ('D', 34)]

End it
```

The code is:

```py
import multiprocessing
import threading


def get_data(data_list):
    print("Get Data call me!")
    for d in data_list:
        print("Why do you not reach here")        
    
def append_data(database, data_list):
    data_list.append(database)

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    print("Start it")
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
        x = [('A',5),('B',3),('C',3)] 
        database = manager.list( x)
        new_data = ('D',34)
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=append_data, args=(new_data, database))
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_data, args=(database,))
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()
        
        print(f"Data is {database}")
    print("End it")
```

I should have mentioned that I am using the IDE Spyder, Python 3.8.8, and it is running on Windows 10.

Comment: After running your exact code (python 3.10, vscode) I get this result : Start it
Get Data call me!
Why do you not reach here
Why do you not reach here
Why do you not reach here
Why do you not reach here
Data is [('A', 5), ('B', 3), ('C', 3), ('D', 34)]
End it

So get_data actually gets called

Comment: Same as Marcel here (python 3.8 on Windows 10)

Comment: What version of Python are you running, on what OS? How are you launching your code (command line, IDE, etc.)? And are you certain the code you're testing is exactly the same as what's shown?

Comment: If you are running under an IDE like `Jupyter Notebook`, then your worker function, `append_data`, must be imported from a module or package. As an aside: The values you are passing to `append_data` are in the reverse order of how they are being declared as arguments in `append_data`. But then instead of having `database.append(data_list)` you have `data_list.append(database)`., so you should end up getting the result you expect (I do when run from the command line). But this is very confusing.

Comment: Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:08:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]


Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.


IPython 8.8.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

runfile('E:/flaskDemo/untitled0.py', wdir='E:/flaskDemo')

Start it

Data is [('A', 5), ('B', 3), ('C', 3), ('D', 34)]

End it


runfile('E:/flaskDemo/untitled0.py', wdir='E:/flaskDemo')

Start it

Data is [('A', 5), ('B', 3), ('C', 3), ('D', 34)]

End it